# Data Grid Template [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

how this type of data grid template can be created??

i can't find any way to make this template.
or can u suggest other way??

i.e. grid view or so and how!

[image: UI]

The last column are not required as of now.

CodeBehind:

```
var pp = from asd in db.OrderMasters
                 select new
                 {
                     asd.CFN,
                     asd.Location,
                     asd.CreatedOn,
                     asd.Quantity
                 };
        dgOrderMaster.ItemsSource = pp.ToList();
```

Markup:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgOrderMaster" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3">
```

Comment: It looks more like `ListView` with custom `ItemTemplate`. Just start on that and you'll see it's not that hard.

Comment: Since you don't use any visual original feature of the listview I would use the `ItemsControl` instead and simply set the template. the item control is similar to the old data repeater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i worked around, and found listview is way more helpfull for my task,
Here's the markup:

```
<ListView Name="lvDataBinding" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Margin="10" Grid.Row="3" Background="{x:Null}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="3" Margin="0,3" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Background="White">
                <Grid Background="White" Margin="0,1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="50,5" >
                        <TextBlock Text="Customer" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding cust}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="Location" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding loc}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="Created On" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding con}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="Quantity" Foreground="#33B6EF" FontSize="20" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding quant}" FontSize="20" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" ShadowDepth="5" />
                </Border.Effect>

            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```